# Ctypes Return Array

Tags: python, c, arrays, pointers, ctypes

I'm trying to have a python wrapper for an array sort function in C.  The C takes the array, sorts the integers by smallest to largest, then returns the array.  But when I run it however, I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sortarray.py", line 25, in <module>
    newarray = sortArray(array)
  File "sortarray.py", line 8, in sortArray
    libsortarray.sortArray.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7f84484280e0, sortArray): symbol not found
```

Python:

```python
import ctypes

libsortarray = ctypes.CDLL('libsortarray.so')

def sortArray(array):
    global libsortarray
    libsortarray.sortArray.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
    arraySize = len(array)
    array_type = ctypes.c_int * arraySize
    result = libsortarray.sortArray(ctypes.c_int(arraySize), array_type(*array))
    return result


file = open('bigarray.txt', 'r')
#Bigarray.txt is just 10,000 lines each with a single integer
array = []
arraySize = 10000
for i in range(0,arraySize):
    array.append(int(file.readline()))
file.close()

newarray = sortArray(array)
print newarray
```

And the libsortarray function

```c
int* sortArray(int, int*);

int* sortArray(int arraySize, int* array) {
    int temp, i, j;
    for (i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
        for (j=i+1; j<arraySize; j++)
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: That worked. Question tho, when I do `for i in newarray` it returns some random integer and what I assume is an address in memory.  It works if I do `for i in range` with `newarray[i]`, but is there a way to be able to still do `for in` with this return type?

Comment: I actually did have restype before but removed it for the post cause it gave me less errors without it.  And when I remove the return types in C to void, it doesn't sort the array.  And if there's no return type it gives me an error when trying to print the array.  So working on that.  But besides that, how can I turn it back into a python type array?  It seems to segfault (Python, not the c code) when I sort the array, then do another function named reverseArray(size, array).  It also takes a while when it should only take around 500ms to segfault.  `newarray=reverseArray(arraySize,newarray)`

Answer (score 5):

If the source is C++, you need to declare the function as `extern "C" int *sortArray(int, int *)`. Also, when a function returns a pointer, set the `restype` attribute to a pointer type, which in this case would be `sortArray.restype = POINTER(c_int)`. Otherwise in a 64-bit process the address gets truncated to 32-bit, creating a bad pointer that will potentially segfault when accessed. Also, and this is more a matter of style, declaring `global libsortarray` and manually wrapping `arraySize` as `c_int(arraySize)` are both unnecessary clutter.

That said, the library function sorts the array in place, so there's no reason to return anything, i.e. just make the return type `void`. Here's an example that implements this suggested modification.

**sortarray.cpp:**

```c++
extern "C" void sortArray(int, int *);

void sortArray(int arraySize, int *array)
{
    int temp, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < arraySize; j++)
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
}

// g++ -shared -fPIC -o libsortarray.so sortarray.cpp
```

**sortarray.py**

```python
import ctypes

libsortarray = ctypes.CDLL('./libsortarray.so')

libsortarray.sortArray.restype = None
libsortarray.sortArray.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, 
                                   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))

def sort_array(array):
    """Return a sorted copy of the input array or sequence."""
    array_size = len(array)
    array = (ctypes.c_int * array_size)(*array)
    libsortarray.sortArray(array_size, array)
    return array

if __name__ == '__main__':
    seq = [7, 0, 8, 4, 3, 6, 9, 1, 5, 2]
    print 'Unsorted Array:\n', seq
    print 'Sorted Array:\n', sort_array(seq)[:]
```

**Output:**

```
Unsorted Array:
[7, 0, 8, 4, 3, 6, 9, 1, 5, 2]
Sorted Array:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```